# MS access 2010 ODBC connection to MySQL

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I've recently learned how to link tables from MySQL to MS access database using OBDC connection but I have the following problem:

The application I am building will have increasing number of tables going to a couple of thousands. I want to create tables in the SQL database using VBA in MS Access.

How can I automatically link those new tables to the Access application right when I create them in the SQL db?
Is this sort of connection the best to use in my case?

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you are writing code in Access VBA that creates MySql tables then you can also write a few more code-lines that links to these tables. Please clarify your question. (I also would ask why you need thousands of tables..?)

Comment: Its an applications with daily information kept in different tables. I know the question isn't clear enough. The main thing is that I am trying to find the best way to build the app, the most appropriate way to connect and edit the SQL database in MS access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same routine where you create the table you should be able to link them to the Access-Project you're in like this:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb()

db.TableDefs("yourTable").Connect = _
 "ODBC;DSN=yourDSN;SERVER=yourServer;" & _
 "PORT=3306;OPTION=12345;" & _
 "DATABASE=yourDB;USER=yourUserName;" & _
 "PASSWORD=yourPassword"
db.TableDefs("yourTable").RefreshLink
```

Find some more useful information [here](http://www.codekabinett.com/page.php?Theme=4&Lang=2)