# PDO vs ODBC for MS Access connection

Tags: mysql, ms-access, pdo, odbc

Would like to know the best practice for connecting to both MySQL and MS Access databases from hosted website. I have an existing site that has been using an MS Access DB for the past 15 years. Hundreds of pages have connection string to the DB, some are DAO, some OLEDB, and others ADO. I'm in the process of trying to move the entire DB over to MySQL but can't move it all at once. Things i'm considering in the move:

- Link Tables in Access to the new MySQL and move data over
- Rewrite all pages in PHP and use PDO connection (usable on both Access / MySQL)
- Use ODBC connection on both (What are advantages vs disadvantages)
- Use existing .NET pages with PDO connection to MySQL.

My desire is to eventually use MySQL DB in place of MS Access but the transition will take months to complete. I need to keep site active until all connection pages are rewritten to connect to MySQL (in PHP)

The attached code is working connection to both DB's - both have limitations to methods available. (Example LIMIT will not work on Access, and CROSSTAB/PIVOT will not work on MySQL)

I'm looking for recommendation on how to accomplish this task of moving over...

helpful post about linking: [MS access 2010 ODBC connection to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23891716/ms-access-2010-odbc-connection-to-mysql)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>PHP and ODBC: PDO Example </title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

/////////////////////////////////////////// ACCESS PDO //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
try{
$mdbFile = "e:\Training.mdb";
$pdo = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=$mdbFile", "", "");

$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName LIKE 'Bar%'");
$query->execute();

echo "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed'>";                  
echo "<thead><tr>";
echo "<th>AutoNum</th><th>User Name</th><th>Email</th>";
echo "</tr></thead>";

  for($i=0; $row = $query->fetch(); $i++){
    echo "<tbody><tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['AutoNum']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['UserName']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Email']."</td>";
  }
echo "</tr></tbody></table>"; 

unset($pdo);
unset($query);

} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo "Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
exit;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//////////////////////////////////////////// MYSQL ODBC //////////////////////////////////////////////////

//  *** THIS WORKS - DON'T CHANGE ***
//$mdbFilename = "e:\Training.mdb";
//$user = "";
//$password = "";
//$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$mdbFilename", $user, $password);

$user = "user";
$password = "password";
$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};SERVER=$mdbFilename; database=MYSQL_training", $user, $password);

if (!$connection) {
    echo "Couldn't make a connection!";
    exit;
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName LIKE 'Bar%'";
$process=odbc_exec($connection, $sql);

echo "<br><br><br>";
echo "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed'>";                  
echo "<thead><tr>";
echo "<th>AutoNum</th><th>User Name</th><th>Email</th>";
echo "</tr></thead>";

while(odbc_fetch_row($process)){
    $username = odbc_result($process, "UserName");
    $email = odbc_result($process, "Email");
    $autonum = odbc_result($process, "AutoNum");

    echo "<tbody><tr>";
    echo "<td>".$autonum."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$username."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$email."</td>";
}

echo "</tr></tbody></table>"; 
odbc_close($connection);
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//////////////////////////////////////////// MYSQL PDO///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$db_mysql = "mysql_training";
$user = "user";
$password = "password";
$pdo = new PDO("odbc:Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};SERVER=$mdbFilename; database=$db_mysql", $user, $password);

try{    

$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName LIKE 'Bar%' LIMIT 3");
$query->execute();

echo "<br><br><br>"; 
echo "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed'>";                  
echo "<thead><tr>";
echo "<th>AutoNum</th><th>User Name</th><th>Email</th>";
echo "</tr></thead>";

  for($i=0; $row = $query->fetch(); $i++){
    echo "<tbody><tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['AutoNum']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['UserName']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Email']."</td>";
  }
echo "</tr></tbody></table>"; 

unset($pdo);
unset($query);

} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo "Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
exit;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *I'm looking for recommendation on how to accomplish this task of moving over...*...move over what? Frontend web design or backend database? Your question is too broad and might be off topic as SO is not here for product recommendation. Please provide a specific item for troubleshooting.

Comment: yes - we have outgrown the Access DB and need to move to MySQL, but the move need to be gradual since the number of pages referencing the Access DB is in the hundreds. I would perfer not to end up writting all the pages to use PDO since mysqli and newer methods are available.

Comment: Simply, rebuild entire site in MySQL in your test environment with PDO and then move over to production when finalized. Crosstabs and other Access SQL dialect all can be translated. And yes, use MySQL linked tables (which you can start using in production) and no local Access tables as you can query linked tables.

Comment: I guess my question comes down to this: If I move my data to MySQL (from ACCESS) my new pages can use any conenction to MySQL - but my existing pages will break... since existing connections are ADO, DAO, OLADB and will no longer work. Best way to keep current pages working while they are rewritten in PHP.

Comment: ok - so how can I accomplish linking the ACCESS table from MySQL in a hosted environment. I don't have access to server or DSN settings?

Comment: Again, this is known as a test bed which you as developer should be using which is a replicated model of live site. Do all new design/test work in this copied environment and then move to production when ready. Keep all as is until then.

Comment: I cannot create DSN, I can conf MySQL from CPanel/phpmyadmin

Comment: Then continue on without linked tables in .mdb file and the night you deploy test to live site migrate all Access table data with .csv/.txt/.xml or PHP action queries to MySQL.